# How to get last caret position of a TextField before unfocus?

Tags: java, javafx

I tried to make a button that can insert a special character into a TextField, and this is my original implementation:

```
// input is a TextField
input.insertText(input.getCaretPosition(), "∞");
```

But I found that it always insert the text to the start, then after some tries, I found that "unfocus" the TextField will make `caretPosition` goes to 0. And that isn't what I want, so I tried to use directly listen to `caretPosition` property like this:

```
AtomicInteger caretPos = new AtomicInteger();
input.caretPositionProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    caretPos.set(newVal.intValue());
    System.out.println(newVal.intValue());
});
```

But the problem is that the listen will still be called when losing focus, which resets `caretPos` to 0 again.

Comment: Why are you using insert with the caret when you can just `input.setText(input.getText() + "..." )`?

Comment: @daniu Because I want to insert the text at specific position (caret position), not append it.

Comment: Does the caret change happen before the change in the `focusProperty`? Can you just check `input.isFocused()` before updating `caretPos`?

Comment: I am guessing you could use a variable with greater scope inside the `TextField's` change listener.

Comment: Maybe use a `KeyListener` to store caret position?

Comment: @James_D Thanks! Checking that solves the problem for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply avoid updating `caretPos` if the text field has lost focus:

```
AtomicInteger caretPos = new AtomicInteger();
input.caretPositionProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
    if (input.isFocused()) {
        caretPos.set(newVal.intValue());
        System.out.println(newVal.intValue());
    }
});
```

Here's a complete working example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextFieldFocusTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        TextField input = new TextField();
        Button insertInfinity = new Button("∞");


        AtomicInteger caretPos = new AtomicInteger();
        input.caretPositionProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            if (input.isFocused()) {
                caretPos.set(newVal.intValue());
            }
        });

        insertInfinity.setOnAction(e -> {
            int pos = caretPos.get();
            input.insertText(pos, "∞");
            input.requestFocus();
            input.positionCaret(pos+1);
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.getChildren().addAll(input, insertInfinity);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setWidth(400);
        primaryStage.setHeight(400);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

}
```