# Javafx indexOutOfBoundsException within Textfield due to caret Postion

Tags: button, javafx, textfield

I'm building a small app where `TextField` text is updated or deleted via buttons on screen. I have utilised code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254473/how-to-get-last-caret-position-of-a-textfield-before-unfocus) to be able to move the caret around and add text. I can add and delete characters within the `TextField` however when *n* amount of characters are added to the `TextField` then *n* amount are removed an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs when you attempt to add another character as the caret position (when all characters are removed) becomes 1 when it should be 0. I do not know why it becomes 1 when it should be 0. What have I done wrong here?

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
```

```java
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Pane panel = new Pane();
            VBox box = new VBox();
            TextField tf = new TextField();
            Button characterButton = new Button("a");
            Button deleteChar = new Button("delete");
            
            box.getChildren().addAll(tf, characterButton, deleteChar );
            panel.getChildren().add(box);
            root.getChildren().add(panel);
            
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            
            //handle caret pos
            AtomicInteger caretPos = new AtomicInteger();
            tf.caretPositionProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
                System.out.println("newval" + newVal);
                if (tf.isFocused()) {
                    caretPos.set(newVal.intValue());
                    System.out.println("Innernewval" + newVal);
                }
            });
            //add character
            characterButton.setOnAction(( event) -> {
                Button btn = (Button)event.getSource();
                System.out.println("Pressed " + btn.getText() + " button");
                int pos = caretPos.get();
                tf.insertText(pos, btn.getText());
                tf.requestFocus();
                tf.positionCaret(pos+1);
                System.out.println("caretPos on add: " + caretPos.get());

            });
            //remove character
            deleteChar.setOnAction(( event) -> {
                Button btn = (Button)event.getSource();
                System.out.println("Pressed " + btn.getText() + " button");
                int newCaretPos = caretPos.get()-1;
                tf.deleteText(newCaretPos, caretPos.get());
                tf.requestFocus();
                tf.positionCaret(newCaretPos);   
                System.out.println("caretPos on delete: " + caretPos.get());
            });
            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem. I click on `characterButton` twice and `tf` contains **aa**. Then I click on `deleteChar` twice and `tf` is empty. Then I click on `characterButton` (once) but I don't get `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` and `tf` contains **a**. I only get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when the `caretPos` is 0 (zero) and I click on `deleteChar`. Did I miss something? Did I do something wrong when I tried to reproduce your problem?

Comment: No what you have done is correct. However when I do the same exact steps as you when I get to this part "Then I click on characterButton (once)" nothing gets added to tf and I get the java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException. I should have noted that I'm on javafx 8... could that maybe be causing me the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not compile. You have a `catch` without a `try`. In the below code, I removed the [orphan] `catch` block. Also, your style sheet, i.e. file *application.css*, is not related to your problem so in order to make the code in your question a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I suggest that you remove that part. It is commented out in the below code.

I only get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when `caretPos` is zero and I press `deleteChar` button. Hence you simply need to add code that handles that [edge case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_case). In the below code, refer to the part after the comment *Handle delete when 'caretPos' is zero.*

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Pane panel = new Pane();
        VBox box = new VBox();
        TextField tf = new TextField();
        Button characterButton = new Button("a");
        Button deleteChar = new Button("delete");

        box.getChildren().addAll(tf, characterButton, deleteChar);
        panel.getChildren().add(box);
        root.getChildren().add(panel);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
//        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        // handle caret pos
        AtomicInteger caretPos = new AtomicInteger();
        tf.caretPositionProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            System.out.println("newval: " + newVal);
            if (tf.isFocused()) {
                caretPos.set(newVal.intValue());
                System.out.println("Innernewval: " + newVal);
            }
        });
        // add character
        characterButton.setOnAction((event) -> {
            Button btn = (Button) event.getSource();
            System.out.println("Pressed " + btn.getText() + " button");
            int pos = caretPos.get();
            tf.insertText(pos, btn.getText());
            tf.requestFocus();
            tf.positionCaret(pos + 1);
            System.out.println("caretPos on add: " + caretPos.get());

        });
        // remove character
        deleteChar.setOnAction((event) -> {
            Button btn = (Button) event.getSource();
            System.out.println("Pressed " + btn.getText() + " button");

            // Handle delete when 'caretPos' is zero.
            if (caretPos.get() == 0) {
                if (tf.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    return; // Nothing to delete.
                }
                else {
                    caretPos.set(1); // Ensure 'newCaretPos' will not be negative.
                }
            }

            int newCaretPos = caretPos.get() - 1;
            tf.deleteText(newCaretPos, caretPos.get());
            tf.requestFocus();
            tf.positionCaret(newCaretPos);
            caretPos.set(newCaretPos);
            System.out.println("caretPos on delete: " + caretPos.get());
        });
    }
}
```

### Edit

You are correct. When I run your code with JavaFX 8, I do reproduce the problem. After some debugging, the problem is that when the `TextField` contains a single character and you press `deleteChar`, the `caretPositionProperty` listener does not run and hence `caretPosition` is **not** updated and remains with the value 1 (one) instead of 0 (zero).

There are probably many workarounds to this problem. I chose to add the below `if` statement after the line `System.out.println("caretPos on delete: " + caretPos.get());` in the event handler for `deleteChar`:

```java
if (tf.getText().isEmpty()) {
    caretPos.set(0);
}
```

For the sake of completeness, here is the code I used to debug the program.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Pane panel = new Pane();
            VBox box = new VBox();
            TextField tf = new TextField();
            Button characterButton = new Button("a");
            Button deleteChar = new Button("delete");
            
            box.getChildren().addAll(tf, characterButton, deleteChar );
            panel.getChildren().add(box);
            root.getChildren().add(panel);
            
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
//            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            
            //handle caret pos
            AtomicInteger caretPos = new AtomicInteger();
            tf.caretPositionProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
                System.out.println("newval" + newVal);
                if (tf.isFocused()) {
                    caretPos.set(newVal.intValue());
                    System.out.println("Innernewval" + newVal);
                }
            });
            //add character
            characterButton.setOnAction(( event) -> {
                Button btn = (Button)event.getSource();
                System.out.println("Pressed " + btn.getText() + " button");
                int pos = caretPos.get();
                System.out.println("###  DBUG  ### -> Adding: [Before 'insertText'] pos = " + pos);
                tf.insertText(pos, btn.getText());
                System.out.println("###  DBUG  ### -> Adding: [Before 'requestFocus'] pos = " + pos);
                tf.requestFocus();
                System.out.println("###  DBUG  ### -> Adding: [Before 'positionCaret'] pos = " + pos);
                tf.positionCaret(pos+1);
                System.out.println("caretPos on add: " + caretPos.get());
            });
            //remove character
            deleteChar.setOnAction(( event) -> {
                Button btn = (Button)event.getSource();
                System.out.println("Pressed " + btn.getText() + " button");
                int newCaretPos = caretPos.get()-1;
                System.out.println("###  DBUG  ### -> Deleting: [Before 'deleteText'] newCaretPos = " + newCaretPos);
                tf.deleteText(newCaretPos, caretPos.get());
                System.out.println("###  DBUG  ### -> Deleting: [Before 'requestFocus'] newCaretPos = " + newCaretPos);
                tf.requestFocus();
                System.out.println("###  DBUG  ### -> Deleting: [Before 'positionCaret'] newCaretPos = " + newCaretPos);
                tf.positionCaret(newCaretPos);   
                System.out.println("caretPos on delete: " + caretPos.get());
                if (tf.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    caretPos.set(0);
                }
            });
            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Here is the output when `TextField` contains a single character and I press `deleteChar`.

```
newval0
Pressed delete button
###  DBUG  ### -> Deleting: [Before 'deleteText'] newCaretPos = 0
###  DBUG  ### -> Deleting: [Before 'requestFocus'] newCaretPos = 0
###  DBUG  ### -> Deleting: [Before 'positionCaret'] newCaretPos = 0
caretPos on delete: 1
```

As you can see, the `caretPositionProperty` listener is not executed.

Comment: Hi, I am a bit confused by the try clause issue. The 5th line has a try clause.... unless I am missing something? I understand the need for the edge case and will add that in however if I run your version of the code I still get the same original issue where the last deleteChar() action instead of setting the caret to 0 sets it to 1. I am running JavaFX 8 could that possibly be related to the issue as you have no issues?

Comment: @rak maybe I made a mistake when I copied the code from your question but my IDE indicated that there was a `catch` with no corresponding `try`.